# Not working: FileUpload validation with ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am developing an image gallery and I want to check if the input file has a file set or not.

This is my try, where only the title is checked, but if the user hasn't set an image it is not detected, what am I doing wrong?

Form

```
namespace Backoffice\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;

class GalerieForm extends Form
{
public function __construct($galerieContent = null)
{
parent::__construct('galerie-form');
$this->setAttribute('action', '/backoffice/galerie/add');
$this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
$this->setAttribute('role', 'form');
$this->setAttribute('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
$this->setInputFilter(new \Backoffice\Form\GalerieFilter());

$this->add(array(
'name' => 'title',
'attributes' => array(
'type' => 'text',
'id' => 'title',
'value' => $galerieContent->title,
'class' => 'form-control'
),
'options' => array(
'label' => 'Picture Title:',
'label_attributes' => array(
'class' => 'control-label'
)
),
));

$this->add(array(
'name' => 'picture',
'attributes' => array(
'type' => 'file',
'id' => 'picture-selector',
'value' => $galerieContent->picture,
'class' => 'btn btn-file',
),
'options' => array(
'label' => 'Picture:',
'label_attributes' => array(
'class' => 'col-xs-1 control-label',
)
),
));

$this->add(array(
'name' => 'update-from',
'attributes' => array(
'type' => 'hidden',
'value' => 'galerie'
),
));

$this->add(array(
'name' => 'submit',
'attributes' => array(
'type' => 'submit',
'value' => 'Update Gallery Content',
'class' => 'btn btn-primary'
),
));

}
}
```

InputFilter

```
namespace Backoffice\Form;

use Zend\Form;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\Validator\File\IsImage;

class GalerieFilter extends InputFilter
{
public function __construct()
{
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'title',
    'required'=> true,
    'filters' => array(
       array('name' => 'StripTags'),
       array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
     ),
     'validators' => array(
         array(
           'name' => 'StringLength',
           'options' => array(
           'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
           'min' => 1,
           'max' => 255,
         ),
      ),
),
));

$this->add(array(
  'name' => 'picture',
  'required'=> true

));

}
}
```

#### Controller

```
public function addAction()
{
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost())
{
    $post = array_merge_recursive(
      $this->getRequest()->getPost()->toArray(),
      $this->getRequest()->getFiles()->toArray()
    );
    var_dump($post);
    $form = new \Backoffice\Form\GalerieForm();
    $form->setData($post);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
      var_dump($post);
    }
}
else {
   $form = new \Backoffice\Form\GalerieForm();
}

return new ViewModel(array(
   'form' => $form
));

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem before, then i putted this into my controller:

```
if ($request->isPost()) {
        $post = array_merge_recursive(
            $request->getPost()->toArray(),
            $request->getFiles()->toArray()
        );
        // To get the required error message
        if (!$post['picture']['tmp_name']) {
            $post['picture'] = null;
        }
        $form->setData($post);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to extend your InputFilter with an additional Valitator e.g. UploadFile which checks if there is an uploaded file. This would be more maintainable than define an additional validation rule within your controller action.

InputFilter code..

```
$this->add(array(
  'name' => 'picture',
  'required' => true,
  'validators' => array(
      new \Zend\Validator\File\UploadFile()
   )
)
```

ZF2 has several standard validators for [File validation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.validator.file.html) and already [InputFilters](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.input-filter.file-input.html) especially for File Uploads.